# Reducing execution time for a python program

Tags: python

The following is code that I used to do a task. the code runs fine but takes over 2 minutes to get executed. And this is with only one rule (Rule_1), the rule is checked using an .exe ( written in CPP).Actually there are many CSV files that are needed to pass through the rules.

My question is will the program always use this much amount of time, because I have to implement more the 50 rule for the files, or there is any other way around?

```
import os
import fnmatch
import subprocess
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
from xml.parsers.expat import ExpatError
import sys
from shutil import copyfileobj


def locate(pattern, root="Z:/Automation/"):
    '''Locate all files matching supplied filename pattern in and below
    supplied root directory.'''
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(root)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            yield os.path.join(path, filename)


csv_path_unrefined = []
for xml in locate("*.csv"):
    try:
        ElementTree.parse(xml)
    except (SyntaxError, ExpatError):
        csv_path_unrefined.append(xml)
csv_path = []
for paths in csv_path_unrefined:
    if "results" in str(paths):
        csv_path.append(paths)


def check_rule1(path):
    # path = "PWLLOGGER_DEMO.csv"
    file = 'ConsoleApplication9.exe "' + path + '"'
   # print(file)
    details = os.popen(file).read()
    log_file = open("logs/Rule_1.txt")
    state = log_file.read()
    with open('results/Rule_1_log.log', 'a+') as files:
        files.write("\n========" + path + "========\n")
        files.close
    with open('results/Rule_1_log.log', 'a+') as output, open('logs/Rule_1.txt', 'r') as input:
        copyfileobj(input, output)
    if "failed" in state:
        return False
    else:
        return True


rule_1_passed = []
rule_1_failed = []

for paths in csv_path:
    result_r1 = check_rule1(paths)
    # print(result_r1)
    if result_r1 == False:
        rule_1_failed.append(paths)
        #print("Rule 1 has failed for " + paths)
    elif result_r1 == True:
        rule_1_passed.append(paths)
        #print("Rule 1 has passed for " + paths)
    open('logs/Rule_1.txt', 'w').close()


print(rule_1_failed)
print(rule_1_passed)
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: So how large are those logfiles the application is creating? You create write, read, overwrite that file again and again...

Comment: You're using an XML reader to parse a CSV file? Could you clarify why that's happening?

Comment: Have you profiled your code to determine which parts are taking the most overall time?

Comment: @scnerd by profiling you mean calculating the time for each function in the program or anything else ?

Comment: @noswear Essentially yes. Profiling is supported natively in Python, please see [the relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) for how specifically to profile your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, to answer your question, you need to profile your code. You need to understand what is taking up all that time. Just by looking at your code, it's impossible to tell, but my guess would be that the most time is spent in one of the following places:

- Running every `*.csv` file you run into through the XML parser. I get the feeling you consider this necessary in order to discard XML files that are pretending to be CSV files. Ideally, you should do this once, then properly label your files thenceforth so you don't have to do this check every time. This strikes me as a potentially very expensive thing to do; as such, I've modified this check below so it only occurs when you might actually be interested in the file later on (that is, its path contains 'results')
- Kicking off the external process individually for each file you want to check. Launching processes is not a cheap operation. Ideally, you'd want to EITHER launch a single process for each rule, passing it all relevant file paths for it to check all at once, OR if you wrote your rules in Python, you could read each file in exactly once, then process it through all your rules all at once. Launching a new process for each rule, for each file, is probably a huge source of slowness.

There are also several parts of the code that just seem hacky and bad practice. Also, if you use Python 3.5+, you can use `glob` instead of your custom `locate` function. In the spirit of reviewing all your code anyway and making any suggestions that seem appropriate, here's how I'd suggest your code be written, though admittedly without any good suggestions about how to speed up the code (because, again, you MUST profile your code to understand what's actually taking the time):

```
import os
import subprocess
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree
from xml.parsers.expat import ExpatError
from glob import iglob



def is_xml(path):
    try:
        ElementTree.parse(path)
        return True
    except (SyntaxError, ExpatError):
        return False


def check_rule1(path):
    subprocess.run(['ConsoleApplication9.exe', path])
    state = open("logs/Rule_1.txt").read()

    with open('results/Rule_1_log.log', 'a+') as output:
        output.write("\n========" + path + "========\n")
        output.write(state)
    return "failed" not in state:


def main():
    csv_path = (path for path in iglob('**/*.csv', recursive=True) if 'results' in path and not is_xml(path))
    rules = [check_rule1]

    for rule_num, rule in enumerate(rules):
        rule_num += 1  # We want to count rules from 1 up
        passed = []
        failed = []

        for paths in csv_path:
            result = rule(paths)
            if result:
                passed.append(paths)
                #print("Rule 1 has passed for " + paths)
            else:
                failed.append(paths)
                #print("Rule 1 has failed for " + paths)

            os.remove('logs/Rule_1.txt')

        # Do something with passed/failed, presumably?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Your second point is also what I thought could be the major problem here, needed to review that one. Also thanks for suggesting the glob function. The help is appreciated.